# Percentage based scan on a timeseries data

Tags: mysql, query, sqlite, time-series-database

I have 20 GB csv file with 650 million rows. The data looks like this:

```
trade_time,price
2020-01-01 00:00:01.481,7189.42
2020-01-01 00:00:01.708,7189.42
2020-01-01 00:00:06.290,7189.5
2020-01-01 00:00:06.291,7190.52
2020-01-01 00:00:07.161,7188.97
2020-01-01 00:00:08.274,7189.93
2020-01-01 00:00:09.277,7190.47
2020-01-01 00:00:09.384,7190.47
2020-01-01 00:00:09.630,7190.11
2020-01-01 00:00:09.848,7189.74
2020-01-01 00:00:10.098,7189.46
2020-01-01 00:00:10.197,7189.16
2020-01-01 00:00:10.351,7189.1
```

I would like to check whether price is up or down by 0.5%. If the price hits +0.5% first, the result is 1. If the price hits -0.5% first, then the result is 0.

At the moment, I'm using [this python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72335956/python-multiprocessing-multiple-large-size-files-using-pandas). If database can perform better for my use case, then I would like to move to the database solution. I don't have a database yet. I have only the csv file.

I'm worried a disk-based solution will be slow.  I'm not seeking persistence here. I'm only looking for a way to finish my task faster. After finishing the task, I don't need the database. So even an in-memory solution is okay for use case.

1. Since my task involves timeseries data, which database is better for my use case? SQL or NoSQL?
2. Is it really possible to do *percentage based* comparison in databases? e.g. +0.5%
3. How long the indexing process usually take for 1 billion rows?

db<>fiddle can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6c76636141055f85734b1caf26bb908).

```
CREATE TABLE Trades (
    trade_time datetime(3)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    price      NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Trades(trade_time,price) VALUES
 ('2020-01-01 00:00:01.481',7189.42)
,('2020-01-01 00:00:01.708',7189.42)
,('2020-01-01 00:00:06.290',7189.5)
,('2020-01-01 00:00:06.291',7190.52)
,('2020-01-01 00:00:07.161',7188.97)
,('2020-01-01 00:00:08.274',7189.93)
,('2020-01-01 00:00:09.277',7190.47)
,('2020-01-01 00:00:09.384',7190.47)
,('2020-01-01 00:00:09.630',7190.11)
,('2020-01-01 00:00:09.848',7189.74)
```

CSV Import to MySQL

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'trades.csv' INTO TABLE Trades
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(trade_time, price);
```

To clarify, I have 5 minute candle data. Each month has 8640 entries. I'm checking for 2 years. So there will be 207,360 entries. I need to take the timetstamp from these 207,360 entries and then perform the check in `Trades` table to check whether the price goes up or down from that point.

I'm not checking all 650 million rows. I'm checking up/down only for the 5 minute candlestick. Those 650 M rows are tick data. One 5 minute candlestick can have 10k trade data, or even 100k trade data during that period if there is momentum. I actually have two tables. 1) 5 minute candles 2) Trades. I have only 200K records in 5 minute candles.

Here are the steps:

1. Get a record from 5 minute candle table.
2. Find the nearest timestamp in 650M table.
3. Loop until the prices hits +0.5% or -0.5%. Whatever hits first, record the result as either 0 or 1.

Up/down by 0.5% is relative to the starting value, but only future values. Here starting value is "nearest timestamp" from the 5 minute record timestamp. For more details, check the code found in [my SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72335956/python-multiprocessing-multiple-large-size-files-using-pandas) as linked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Discussing a implementation using MySQL)

```
CREATE TABLE Trades (
    trade_time DATETIME(3) NOT NULL, -- millisecond resolution
    price DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,     -- or possibly something else
    PRIMARY KEY(trade_time)          -- UNIQUE and an INDEX
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

You seem to be concerned about only one stock, correct?  (If not then `PRIMARY KEY (stock_id, trade_time)` in that order.)

($start and $start_ts come from your app that is building and running the query.  They need to hold the beginning price and time.)

```
SELECT ts, price
     FROM Trades
     WHERE trade_time > $start_ts,
       AND ABS(price - $start) / $start > 0.005  -- up or down .5%
     ORDER BY trade_time ASC
```

to find the *next* time when the `price` has moved by 0.5%.  Similarly, use `<` and `DESC` to find the *previous* time.

```
SELECT ts, price, 
       price > $start   -- 1 when TRUE; 0 when FALSE
     FROM Trades
     WHERE trade_time > $start_ts,
       AND ( (price - $start) / $start > 0.005  -- up .5%
          OR (price - $start) / $start < 0.003  -- up .3%
           )
     ORDER BY trade_time ASC
```

Because of the indexing and clustering, this query will take [typically] less than 1ms.  (Of course, if the price takes a month to move by .5%, the query will take much longer.)

A 5-minute candle (with just lo, avg, hi) is probably done via:

```
SELECT  MIN(trade_time) as lo,
        AVG(trade_time) as avg,
        MAX(trade_time) as hi
    FROM Trades
    WHERE trade_time >= $start_ts
      AND trade_time  < $start_ts + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

The candle query should be run once every 5 minutes and saved in another table with 4 columns: trade_time, lo, avg, hi.  It will take time to catch up with the data you already have, but future data should be computed on a 5-minute EVENT or cron.

It will take time to get the `PRIMARY KEY` in place.  But once in place, new data will arrive just as fast as before.  It may take hour(s) to add the PK.

Comment: Hi, Just noticed you edited this answer with more details. Thanks for that. I'm using your solution and it is very fast indeed. I have a little query. Hope you wouldn't mind.  This line utilises a single value for BOTH up and down. `ABS(price - $start) / $start > 0.005`. I would like to use different values. i.e. For Up, I would like to use 0.005 (0.5%) and for down I would like to use 0.003 (0.3%). Could you tell me how to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: If possible, I would like the query to return the `result` as well. If up value (0.005) hits first, then the result is 1. if down value (0.003) hits first, then the result is zero. Thanks.

Comment: I added an up/down example.  But figuring out which happens first is much more complex.  (And likely to be much slower.)

Comment: What version of MySQL?  8.0 has some "windowing functions" that may be needed.

Comment: I'm actually using sqlite3 since I'm doing everything inmemory. `con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")`. If figuring out what happens first is complex via normal query, could you add `duration` in the result? It is the timestamp difference. So I can perform the query TWICE. one in normal mode. Another query by reversing the percentage values. I'll keep the one which contains less duration. e.g. Normal Result 1 (6.6 seconds),  Reversed Result 0 (6.5 seconds). In this case, the final result is `0`. Thanks

Comment: I think there is a bug in your updated query. I'm getting the same result for all rows.

Comment: Just figure out the bug. In SQLite, this line causing the issue. `price > $start   -- 1 when TRUE; 0 when FALSE`

Comment: Figured the duration part. `SELECT trade_time, price, ((julianday(trade_time)-julianday($start_ts))*(86400000)) AS duration`

Comment: @John - or `TO_DAYS(..)`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. It seems like my SQL queries are slow. The CREATE TABLE code you provided in this answer, only create the trade_time index via `PRIMARY KEY(trade_time)`. Since we are scanning the table by price, do I have the create an index by price?  Thanks.

Comment: @John - I won't hurt to add `INDEX(price)`, but none of the `SELECTs` we have discussed will benefit from it.